# "Proof" that $\text{cof}(\omega_\lambda)<\omega_\lambda$ if $\lambda$ is a nonzero limit ordinal

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

The following lemma is from [this](http://www.math.unt.edu/~moliver/fa04s/JacksonNotes/card.pdf) introduction to cardinals.

> **Lemma 2.7.** Let $\omega_\alpha$ be a limit cardinal. Then $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal and $\text{cof}(\omega_\alpha)=\text{cof}(\alpha)$.

I understand the proof of this lemma, including the proof of relevant lemma 2.4 (beware, there is a typo in that proof: $g$ instead of $h$).

Now I want to use it to make the following conclusion:

$$\text{cof}(\omega_\lambda)\stackrel{2.7}=\text{cof}(\lambda)\leq \lambda < \omega_\lambda$$

However, in the same paper I'm being told that the existence of regular limit cardinals is independent of ZFC! So there must be a flaw in my conclusion.

I can think of two things that would undermine my argument:

1. $\lambda < \omega_\lambda$ is not always true.
2. For a nonzero limit ordinal $\lambda$, $\omega_\lambda$ need not be a limit cardinal.

But I don't see how either 1. or 2. is possible.

Comment: Regarding 2.: Note that $\omega_{\lambda}$ is always a limit cardinal, for limit ordinals $\lambda$. You should try to prove this fact (it's easy).

Comment: As the answers have indicated, point 1. is correct: $\alpha\mapsto\aleph_{\alpha}$ is a [normal ordinal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_function) and therefore has fixed points. The regular fixed points, if any, are the (weakly) inaccessible cardinals, and their existence is independent of ZFC.

Comment: So $\lambda = \omega_\lambda$ is a necessary condition for $\lambda$ to be a regular limit cardinal but it's not provable that it is a sufficient condition.

Comment: @Stefan: Let me try. Suppose $|\alpha|=|\omega_\lambda|$ for some $\alpha<\omega_\lambda$, then $|\omega_{\alpha+1}|>|\omega_\alpha|$ but $|\omega_\lambda|\geq |\omega_{\alpha+1}|$, so it is a cardinal. If it was a successor then $\lambda$ would be a successor as well, so it is a limit cardinal. (btw is there a preview function for comments? x_^)

Comment: .There are  also singular cardinals satisfying $x=\omega_x$. See my A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s the first alternative: it’s not always true that $\lambda<\omega_\lambda$. Let $\lambda_0=\omega$, and for $n\in\omega$ let $\lambda_{n+1}=\omega_{\lambda_n}$. Let $\lambda=\sup_n\lambda_n$; then

$$\lambda=\sup_n\lambda_n=\sup_n\omega_{\lambda_n}=\omega_{\sup_n\lambda_n}=\omega_\lambda\;.$$

Comment: Very interesting construction! Is this the least element of the class $C$ in Brian's answer? Also, this $\lambda$ would be a candidate for a regular limit cardinal, right? Does this mean its cofinality is undecided in ZFC?

Comment: @akkarin Of course not. The construction tells you explicitly what the cofinality of $\lambda$ is.

Comment: Ahh – the cofinality is just $\omega$?! Because $n\mapsto \lambda_n$ is already cofinal? This seems so little for such a huge set! Also, if I got this right now, for any limit cardinal $\kappa$ we investigate we would always find $\text{cof}(\kappa)<\kappa$, right? However, we won't be able to prove this in general.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Brian's answer: We can prove (in $\operatorname{ZF}$) that $C := \{ \lambda \in \operatorname{On} \mid \lambda = \omega_{\lambda} \}$ is a unbounded proper class. (When I talk about proper classes in $\operatorname{ZF}$, I always mean virtual classes.)

A slight variation of Brian's answer shows that $C$ is unbounded. Given some $\gamma \in \operatorname{On}$, let $\lambda_{0} = \gamma$ and then $\lambda_{n+1} = \omega_{\lambda_{n}}$. It follows that $\lambda := \sup \{ \lambda_{n} \mid n < \omega \}$ satisfies $\lambda = \omega_{\lambda}$. I leave it to you to prove that $C$ is closed as well.

You may also want to check that for any uncountable and regular cardinal $\kappa$, $C_{\kappa} := C \cap \kappa$ is club in $\kappa$.

Comment: Thanks for the adding this. The unboundedness is due to the fact that you can choose $\gamma$ arbitrarily big, right? I'll think about how to prove $C$ is closed, it's not immediately clear to me.

Comment: @akkarin Right. Closure follows (pretty much immediatly) from the definition of $\omega_{\lambda}$ for limit ordinals $\lambda$. Let me know, if you get stuck.